# I want to save data generated by HTML form to JSON file

Tags: html, json, forms, dom-events, form-submit

I want to save data generated from a an HTML form to JSON file in my computer, I'm totally new in the field. I have attached below the HTML and JavaScript code.

```
<form id="test" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="check">Check if you like JavaScript</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="yes" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select">Select your favorite JavaScript framework</label>
        <select name="select" class="form-control">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
            <option value="jquery">jQuery</option>
            <option value="angularjs">Angular</option>
            <option value="mine">Mine, of course!</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Leave a message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
    </p>
</form> 
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

```
(function() {
    function toJSONString( form ) {
        var obj = {};
        var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select, textarea" );
        for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var name = element.name;
            var value = element.value;

            if( name ) {
                obj[ name ] = value;
            }
        }

        return JSON.stringify( obj );
    }

    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var form = document.getElementById( "test" );
        var output = document.getElementById( "output" );
        form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var json = toJSONString( this );
            output.innerHTML = json;

        }, false);

    });

})();
```

Instead of displaying the JSON content I want to store it in a JSON file.

Comment: When you say you want to save the file on "your" computer, do you mean the computer viewing the web page in a web browser, or do you mean the computer that is hosting the web page?

Comment: I mean the computer viewing the web page , thanks for your reply